# Kubuntu: Accessing mongodb?

Tags: mongodb, ubuntu

Trying to get started with mongodb and linux at all, so got a preety stupid question, but anyways. How can i get into the mongodb(cmd) to send some of my queries.
Used 
sudo mongodb serive start 
already and cheked it's status, how can I access that space where i can type my queries?

Comment: You're looking for the mongo shell maybe? https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/mongo/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The command is just `mongo`.

```
$ mongo
MongoDB shell version: 3.2.1
connecting to: test
Server has startup warnings: 
2018-08-14T13:55:45.280-0400 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] 
2018-08-14T13:55:45.280-0400 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] ** WARNING: /sys/kernel/mm/transparent_hugepage/defrag is 'always'.
2018-08-14T13:55:45.280-0400 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] **        We suggest setting it to 'never'
2018-08-14T13:55:45.280-0400 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] 
> exit
bye
```

Comment: My thanks, that worked (preety strange that i couldn't google that)